# Can I use QWebSocket library of Qt5.3 in Qt4 project?

Tags: qt, qt5.3

I'm going to use QWebSocket library in qt4 project.

But QWebSocket is qt5.3 version.

Is it possible to compile QWebSocket source files as Qt4 additional library?

Comment: `QWebSocket` is a class, not a library. No, you can't because all Qt modules depents on QtCore library.

Comment: probably not, you will run into weird problem (like crash in QString), even you cheated compiler. Speaking from my own experience ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I think to implement QWebSocket by using Qt4 modules.
Is it possible?